# Remove records from table 1 if it's combination of values on two fields can not be found in Table 2

Tags: plsql

I have a table structure like this:
Table 1 contains col_a, col_b, col_c 
Table 2 contains col_a, col_b

I would like to be able to check if there are any records in Table 1 that have values in col_a and col_b that do NOT match any of the records in Table 2, based on the col_a and col_b values. Whist also, using DBMS_OUTPUT to log what has been removed.

So if this was my data:

Table 1

```
--------------------------------------
       |col_a   | col_b     | col_c   |
--------------------------------------
Row 1 |'apple' | 'ham'     | 'water' |
------------------------------------
Row 2 |'pear'  | 'chicken' | 'water' |
-------------------------------------
Row 3 | 'apple' | 'pork'   | 'wine'  |
--------------------------------------
```

Table 2

```
----------------------------
      |col_a    | col_b     | 
----------------------------
Row 1 |'apple'  | 'ham'     |
----------------------------
Row 2 |'pear'   | 'pork'    |
----------------------------
Row 3 | 'orange'| 'chicken' |
----------------------------
```

In table 1, Rows 2 and 3 would be removed.

I have tried the code below, but it returns nothing. I take it that is because I compare all of col_a, then all of col_b, but not together.

```
delete from table_1 t1
where t1.col_a not in (select t2.col_a from table_2 t2)
and t1.col_b not in  (select t2.col_b from table_2 t2)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You use || for concatening :
Should be like that :

```
delete from table_1 t1
where t1.col_a || '-' || t1.col_b not in (select t2.col_a || '-' || t2.col_b from table_2 t2) ;
```

'-' is a separator, ideally it can be any character you are not supposed to have in the data.

A sql script could be like that (I didn't tested and didn't write code for deletion) :

```
set serveroutput on;



  DECLARE 
  CURSOR MY_CURSOR IS  select * from table_1 t1 where t1.col_a || '-' || t1.col_b not in (select t2.col_a || '-' || t2.col_b from table_2 t2) ;    
  COUNTER NUMBER :=0;  
  begin  
  FOR MYCUR IN MY_CURSOR LOOP

         BEGIN      
            -- SQL DELETE HERE

            -- LOG :
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('row deleted'); 
            COUNTER := COUNTER + 1 ;
          EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS THEN
          DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('ERROR =>  ' || SQLERRM);
          END;
  END LOOP ;  
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Total : '||COUNTER );
  END;  
  /
```

Comment: Oh that's great! Thanks @Jean-ChristopheBlanchard Do you know how to incorporate the DBMS_OUTPUT to give me a log of what has been deleted?

Comment: If you want a log I think you can make a cursor and inside the cursor you delete each line and make output:CURSOR MY_CURSOR IS  select * from table_1 t1 where t1.col_a || '-' || t1.col_b not in (select t2.col_a || '-' || t2.col_b from table_2 t2) ;

Comment: Thanks again. I will mark your answer as accepted. As you answered my original question. I will now look into  your answer/comments related to cursors to see if it works for me. Hopefully I should not need any further assistance.

Comment: Yes, I have now seen your edited answer. :D - Cheers

Comment: It's **wrong** way. Instead of it using `select * from table_1 t1 where (t1.col_a , t1.col_b) not in (select t2.col_a , t2.col_b from table_2 t2)`

Comment: Thanks @StepanKasyanenko

Answer (score 2):

In order to achieve your desired results, use `IN` in the `select`.

This allows you to use multiple parameters in the select.

Like this

```
delete from table_1 t1 
where (t1.col_a,t1.col_b) not in (select t2.col_a,t2.col_b from table_2 t2)
```

More detail about [IN](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/conditions013.htm).

Comment: Interesting I didn't know this method.